# Unable to access the Angular page being served by WebStorm using public IP

Tags: angularjs, http-status-code-404, webstorm

I am running one Angular application using WebStorm's internal web server. I am able to access all the pages and resources using private IP address. I assigned one public IP to the same PC so that I can access it using public IP address. But only the page html content is being displayed and none of the css or js files are accessible.

Unable to understand how come I am accessing all pages using private IP address of the machine but not through its public IP.

```
HTML PAGE URL: http://{PUBLIC IP}:8080/SmartBin/SmartBin-Admin.html#
CSS RESOURCE : http://{PUBLIC IP}:8080/SmartBin/css/style.css - here getting 404 not found error.
```

This is happening for all the resources that are being referred by above html page.

I am invoking other resources as

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> from the above html page
```

Comment: Individually i am able to access each js and css resources using the URL. But webstorm is returning 404 response whenever i am accessing the html page from which the resources are being accessed.

Comment: <meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer" /> this line helped in resolving the issue.

Comment: Satya, thanks, this helped me! I logged an issue with jetbrains about it as well; in case others have the same issue I'll link it here: youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28826